# Geometry problem; right triangles in a square

Tags: geometry

> Given square ABCD with E the midpoint of CD. Join A to E and drop a perpendicular from B to AE at F. Assign coordinates D(0,0), C(20,0), B(20,20) and A(0,20). Find the coordinates of F.
>
> [image]

If I have to find the coordinates of F, do I have to find the horizontal and vertical distance from D to F (since D is taken to be the origin). Obviously I can use the Pythagorean theorem to find certain lengths. Any hints?

Comment: hint: triangles $ADE$ and $BFA$ are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we call $\angle DAE = t,$ then $\tan t = \frac 12, \cos t = \frac 2{\sqrt 5}, \sin t = \frac 1{\sqrt 5}$. let $AF = x,$  then $FB = 2x$ by phythagoras theorem $5x^2 = 20^2 \to x = 4\sqrt 5$ the $x$-cdt of $F$ is $4\sqrt 5\sin t = 4$ and the $y$-cdt of $F$ is $20 - 4\sqrt 5 \cos t= 12.$

therefore $$F = (4, 12) $$

Comment: the justification is $\angle DEA = \angle BAF = 90^\circ - \angle DAE.$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Draw FG such that FG is perpendicular to AB.

In order to locate point F we have to find distances FG and AG.

Angles in green and blue are complementary. All angles marked in green are equal, as are all angles marked in blue. Therefore triangles ADE, BFA, BGF and FGA are similar.
$$AE^2=AD^2+DE^2=20^2+10^2=500$$
$$AD=AB=20, DE=10$$

Area of $\Delta ADE$ : Area of $\Delta BFA$ = $(\frac{AE}{AB})^2$ therefore
$$\frac{AD.DE}{AB.FG}=\frac{10}{FG}=\frac{500}{400}$$
$$FG=\frac45 \times 10 = 8$$

By similarity of triangles FGA and ADE we have 
$$\frac{FG}{AG}=\frac{AD}{DE}=2$$
$$AG=\frac{FG}{2}=4$$

So the co-ordinates of point F are $(4, 12)$.